# Miracast over infrastructure

Tags: miracast

I'm trying to make Miracast over Infrastructure work, with no success until now.

In particular, i'd like to connect my Microsoft Surface Pro 4 (W10 v1909) to my workstation (also with updated W10 1909) in order to use the Surface as secondary screen and input device (with the pen).

I tried various thing, including:

- connecting both the devices via WiFi (using a wifi-USB adapter in the workstation) --> it worked just once in the wrong direction, namely casting the surface on the workstation monitor, and then it stopped with an error message (private content something, sorry can't remember). Moreover, i couldn't see the SURFACE from the workstation. (In this case the connection should have been a normal MiraCast over wifi, am I right?)
- connecting the Surface via WiFi, the workstation via LAN (this is the ideal configuration) --> no sign of the Surface in the "Connect" menu of the WS, and no sign of the WS in the corresponding menu in the SURFACE.
- connecting both the devices via LAN (using an USB-ethernet adapter for the surface) --> nothing worked, nothing appeared in the "connecting" page of both the devices.

Every connection in all the setups is setted to "Private", and (when possible) the "Project on this PC" option is enabled.

What should i do?

I looked for the problem on the internet, and i couldn't find any working solution. Sometimes they mention an "enterprise network": is this a particular kind of network? How does it work? Do you think this is a specific request in order for the thing to work?

Thank you for your attention and kind reply.

---

In the following you find the (fisrt lines of the) results of the dxdiag command on both the devices, connected in the second way explained above.
If I can provide other informations in order to address the problem, let me know!

---

### System Information - WORKSTATION

```
  Time of this report: 3/9/2020, 13:45:48
         Machine name: WORKSTATION
     Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 18363) (18362.19h1_release.190318-1202)
             Language: Italian (Regional Setting: Italian)
  System Manufacturer: System manufacturer
         System Model: System Product Name
                 BIOS: 4024 (type: UEFI)
            Processor: AMD Ryzen 7 2700X Eight-Core Processor          (16 CPUs), ~3.7GHz
               Memory: 16384MB RAM
  Available OS Memory: 16316MB RAM
            Page File: 11031MB used, 10916MB available
          Windows Dir: C:\WINDOWS
      DirectX Version: DirectX 12
  DX Setup Parameters: Not found
     User DPI Setting: 144 DPI (150 percent)
   System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
      DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
             Miracast: Available, with HDCP
```

Microsoft Graphics Hybrid: Not Supported
 DirectX Database Version: Unknown
           DxDiag Version: 10.00.18362.0387 64bit Unicode

**EDIT**: the GPU of my workstation is an nVIDIA GTX 980 Ti (from Gigabyte).

---

---

### System Information - SURFACE

```
  Time of this report: 3/9/2020, 13:53:37
         Machine name: SURFACE
     Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 18363) (18362.19h1_release.190318-1202)
             Language: Italian (Regional Setting: Italian)
  System Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation
         System Model: Surface Pro 4
                 BIOS: 108.2706.768 (type: UEFI)
            Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6650U CPU @ 2.20GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.2GHz
               Memory: 8192MB RAM
  Available OS Memory: 8118MB RAM
            Page File: 2947MB used, 6450MB available
          Windows Dir: C:\WINDOWS
      DirectX Version: DirectX 12
  DX Setup Parameters: Not found
     User DPI Setting: 192 DPI (200 percent)
   System DPI Setting: 192 DPI (200 percent)
      DWM DPI Scaling: UnKnown
             Miracast: Available, with HDCP
```

Microsoft Graphics Hybrid: Not Supported
 DirectX Database Version: Unknown
           DxDiag Version: 10.00.18362.0387 64bit Unicode

---

Comment: What GPU does your workstation have?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: Due to many reasons, just because you are being told Miracast is Available does not actually mean your hardware supports it.  The only GPU I am aware that is guaranteed to support Miracast is Intel's iGPU on the Surface Pro 4

Comment: I have an nVIDIA gtx 980 TI, as said in the EDIT.

Comment: You included that information after I submitted a comment.  The current Nvidia drivers do not even support Miracast.  Only your Surface Pro 4 supports Miracast and that’s only because of the Intel CPU you have installed.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I didn't find any mention to the Intel CPU as a requirement... Thank you for the explanation. (and sorry, i didn't know how to notify you of the EDIT i made!)
What should i do now? Should i delete the question?

Comment: I have simply done research on the subject.  It's not specifically documented by Nvidia nor AMD that their current display drivers do not support Miracast.  I have simply combined together information from individual user reports.

Comment: I have to enable my Intel integrated graphics in the BIOS to get Miracast to work. Hilariously, when actually using Miracast, it then continues to use my nVidia discrete GPU to do the encoding. It just seems to be a licensing issue (sigh). Miracast in Windows is full of these arbitrary limitations, such as very high latency when using anything other than 'games mode', and requiring Wi-Fi adapters supporting 'Wifi direct' even when the stream goes over Ethernet and service discovery over Ethernet has existed for decades. I hope Microsoft puts some effort into polishing this feature..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Miracast requires a capable Wi-Fi adapter, even if you want to use Miracast over infrastructure. Microsoft claims that's necessary for device discovery. I don't agree, but that's how it is.

You can check this by opening a command prompt (Windows+R > `cmd`) and checking the output of `netsh wlan show driver`. At the very bottom of the output it should show:

```
Wireless Display Supported: Yes (Graphics Driver: Yes, Wi-Fi Driver: Yes)
```

There are probably quite a few USB Wi-Fi dongles that support this. I know for sure that any dongle based on the Realtek 8811CU will work. I think any dongle supporting Wi-Fi Direct should work, but I'm not 100% sure.